# MongoException comes while Inserting some Documents in Mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa

In my application, I use spring-data-jpa and Mongo database and tomcat8 as an application server.
All are at AWS instance.

While inserting records, I got this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Size 16915712 is larger than MaxDocumentSize 16793600.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: Size 16915712 is larger than MaxDocumentSize 16793600.
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1946)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:412)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:905)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:721)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:676)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Can someone help me solve the exception?

Comment: You are trying to insert too large document. Mongo has a maximum of 16M for a single document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB has a maximum document size of 16 MB. You cannot insert documents larger than that. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents

You can use GridFS to split the documents that are more than 16 MB in size.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: You can use GridFS to split the documents. However it will use 2 collections in order to facilitate this. One collection is for chunked data and the other is for relevant meta data. More info here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: thanks for helping me out I am going to implement gridFs